# 2 figures in 2 rows, not getting aligned properly

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am trying to put 2 plots from matlab one above the other using subfigure. However, they are not getting aligned properly. Also, can anyone please advice as to how the text on the graph axis can be made more readable. I cannot see it properly what's there on the X and Y axis. I am sorry for posting so badly. I am new here and dont know how to do it properly. please advice

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering

    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=6cm,width=12cm]{kaimal}
    \caption{Kaimal spectrum drawn to log normal scale}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=6cm,width=12cm]{time_series}
    \caption{Wind speed time series}
  \end{subfigure}  
  \caption{A Kaimal spectrum and a wind speed time series derived from it} 
   \label{fig:km}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE! It seems, that your images hasn't equal size. Since you scaled them to the same width, they are distorted. Also it seems that first one white border on the left. So, first you must edit images (the best in Matlab), that they will be equal.

Comment: add `\fbox{\includegraphics[height=6cm,width=12cm]{kaimal}}` and `\fbox{\includegraphics[height=6cm,width=12cm]{time_series}}`to see.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I don't like box around my figures. Is it possible?? Also, can something be done about the unreadable text size on the X and Y axes.  This is my code for labeling axes in Matlab....xlabel('$$\textbf{Frequency}$$ $$ \textbf{[Hz]}$$','Interpreter','latex','FontSize',10)

ylabel('$$\textbf{S(f)}$$$$\frac{(m/s)^2}{[Hz]}$$','Interpreter','latex','FontSize',10)

Comment: the suggestion for adding `\fbox` was just for debugging, so that you can see the extent of the image, not for the final version.

Comment: You almost never want to do this: `height=6cm,width=12cm]`  just scale by height or width _not_ both otherwise you will distort the images as you show.

Comment: As for readability, I recommend setting the correct size of the figure in Matlab, so you don't have to do any rescaling in LaTeX. Haven't used Matlab much in a while, but I used to do that with [`figuresize.m`](https://github.com/wspr/matlabpkg/blob/master/figuresize.m), though there are surely other options available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. I found somewhere that by using

\pgfplotsset{yticklabel style={text width=3em,align=right}}

they get aligned perfectly. Thank you for your help guys.